# SQL Server update two database

Tags: sql-server

```
update [korova].[dbo].[Goods] 
set [korova].[dbo].[Goods].idgoods=[gusfand].[dbo].[Goods].ID
where [korova].[dbo].[Goods].idOutGoods=[gusfand].[dbo].[Goods].Code
```

the error is:

> The multi-part identifier "gusfand.dbo.Goods.ID" could not be bound

Comment: good people where the error? I do not know please help.

Comment: What with the question?

Comment: where the error I do not understand.

Comment: You don't say anything in your question, please update it and post what you are trying to do and what is the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont write the table you change before the column in the set part.

mention the table where the data comes from:

```
update dest
set idgoods=src.ID
from [korova].[dbo].[Goods] dest 
join [gusfand].[dbo].[Goods] src on dst.idOutGoods=src.Code
```